# How to find server domain name for SMTP from PHP?

Tags: php, apache, server-name

I have cPanel servers which run the same script, but I've hard coded the server name in to the code as I can't find anywhere to grab the actual server domain.

Imagine 3 cPanel servers and these are the server domains:

```
apple.hosting.com
banana.hosting.com
carrot.hosting.com
```

While running a PHP script to send mail via SMTP, I need to connect to the server and want to use the server name that would be provided for secure connections.

I don't want to create an array of the IP addresses and then have it compare, as that won't work with dedicated IP addresses.

I tried ini_get('SMTP'), which just returns a useless 'localhost'.

I tried ini_get_all(null,false), and no joy.

I checked the $_SERVER global, but only the domain being accessed appeared.

The only thing that returned the server name was phpinfo().

Comment: what do you mean, domain name? domain of a site you'll be hosting on that server, or the server's own network hostname?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a while to find this, and in composing the question, I found the answer. Rather than waste what I think is a good question (since I couldn't find the answer easily), here it is:

New as of PHP 5.3:

```
gethostname();
```

That's it, nice and sweet.

Read more here: [PHP function gethostname](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostname.php)

Comment: I don't think that @Exit is asking for the domain name that it's hosted on, I think that he is actually trying to find out the mail server or domain name for his/hers SMTP.

Answer (score 0):

You could send yourself an email an look in the email header (In Outlook: Open the mail, View->Options, there is 'Internet headers)

The normal sub-domain is mail.domain.com, and another solution could be:

Follow this:
`cpanel --> go to your mailing accounts -- > click on configure mail account -- > there somewhere in the page you will get the information about your smtp server`

And on that page you should find the information.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [mxtoolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com/diagnostic.aspx)

Other then that, you'll probably want to check [stream-socket-client](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-client.php)